# Advice on setting up a Local Wordpress Development Environment

Tags: wordpress

up until now my relationship with developing wordpress sites has been directly on the remote/live server. I now need to be more efficient with my workflow and wondered if anyone could give me any advice on setting up a local wordpress development environment? Which tools/approaches do you use? I know it can be down to personal taste. I see WAMP, MAMP and others like Vagrant and Docker are being used. I have never used any of these so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Normally my workflow for other non-wordpress sites I use command line to run Gulp to compile sass, watch files, reload browser etc. I'm sure I can use Gulp in the same way for a local wordpress development environment?

Thanks for reading - any responses or advice are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My personal setup consists of using MAMP to setup the site, it's simple and it offers everything you  will need for a fully functionality WordPress development environment. Vagrant and Docker are great, but they are overkill in most circumstances.

For theme development, I still use Gulp to compile SASS, watch files and live reload (and whatever else you want to do, e.g. minify CSS, compress images, etc.). You can use these tools when developing for WordPress (in the case of BrowserSync, just provide the localhost url that MAMP generates, rather than the dir location).

Although theme development + gulp might seem intimidating at first, you'd be surprised how similar it is to basic website development once you get setup.

There's a lot of great tutorials on 'advanced WordPress workflows'. For example, [this tutorial](http://wasimbhalli.com/configuring-gulp-and-browsersync-for-wordpress-_s-theme/) is quite insightful.

Comment: Thanks Adam, In my research so far it did seem like MAMP would be easier to get up and running with. Vagrant/Docker seemed a little more complex to set up. Your set up sounds like it would be a good fit for me. Will have a look at the tutorial you linked to. Thanks so much for the advice!

Comment: No problem, Craig. Let me know how you get on!

Comment: If you want to try docker, you can create image with all dependencies, push it in docker hub and use it every time. You can then use some shell scripting to improve your workflow. You can try this project as reference, https://github.com/ankitpokhrel/wp-dev, it will help you setup your dev env using simple yaml configuration. It is capable of provisioning databases, installing plugins, themes and setting up project from git source.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use MAMP, I create a new [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) project (which is using Gulp) to manage/create my assets. I make a symbolic link to my assets/dist, which contains my css, js, images, etc.

This allows me to have clean & ready assets in my Wordpress. If you don't use any framework, the principle stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a good environment for developing WordPress plugins, checkout wp-plugin-devkit.  It runs on top of Docker, but does not require any Docker knowledge.

https://github.com/jamrizzi/wp-plugin-devkit